# What causes the "file" command to report a JavaScript file as "HTML document text"?

Tags: command-line, file, javascript, html

I downloaded a JavaScript document, but it fails to load in my webpage, stating that the mimetype of "" is not acceptable. When I use the file(1) command on the JavaScript file, it tells me that the file is "HTML document text".  The file looks roughly like this:

```
/*
   some boring attribution, etc.
*/
$(function($) {
     a lot of javascript, including a few lines that add HTML to the page, such as
     _base.append('<a style="background-color:'+_settings._main_btn_color+'" href="javascript:void(0)" class="_col_shadow _collapz_parant _close"></a>');
}(jQuery));
```

I know the file command uses various patterns to make its determination, I'm just wondering what it is that is triggering its decision.

Comment: I've removed your second question, as it's easier for everybody if one question post focuses on one question only. You can always ask the second question separately, but I would recommend to consult the Apache httpd documentation first (and do some research on the topic).

Comment: Also, it might help to actually see the exact file to see whether there is anything which triggers `file` into thinking this is an HTML file.

Comment: What's the file extension?

Comment: The pattern definitions are over in`/usr/share/file/magic`.  A file has to have a 'nodejs' header for it to be called a javascript file (kinda dumb imo). For HTML files, it searches for typical headings: <head> <title> <html> <a href=>.  So that's why your JS file was identified as HTML.

Comment: @nohillside - Thanks for removing the second question - do you remember what it was? Next time, ask the OP to make the split.

Comment: Sure I do, it's clearly visible in the [edit history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/435812/revisions)

Comment: @aMike - "file", "document" - splitting hairs, IMHO. It's a file on the disk, it's a document inside the file...

Answer (score 1):

The original question arose because the server did not correctly provide the MIME type of the file:

> I download a javascript but it fails to load in my page, stating that the mimetype of "" is not acceptable.

To solve the root problem of the served MIME type, ensure the file extension is `.js` or `.javascript`.

This will help the server correctly identify the contents and set the MIME type appropriately.

Comment: My original post I called it a Javascript file and it does have the .js extension. My understanding of file/magic is various patterns are applied to the file's contents and I *thought* the extension was somewhat ignored because this is *NIX, not Window$.

Comment: @user3481644 Originally I read the question as being about the web server not setting the correct MIME type when serving a Javascript file. Your comment rather indicates that the question is rather about `file` not recognizing a JS file. Which one is it?